# How to use iTune's API to download a file and import the string using python?

Tags: python, itunes-store

iTune has an API that lets me download a file about an app.

When I type in https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software, it prompts me to download a file.

Is there a command in python that downloads the file and import the string into a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the contents of the file you can simply do:

```
import requests
string_var = requests.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software").content
```

Seeing, that the response is a JSON-file you would probably want to add:

```
import json
resp_dict = json.loads(string_var)
```

This will give you a dictionary to work with

These are just  small snippets. I used Python2.7

Comment: I'm guessing I can't directly import it? So I have to download it to a file then read it?